# Steam in boiler from evaporation not boiling

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, water, gas, evaporation

Vapor pressure inside a closed container keeps building up and the boiling point of water become higher. What if the steam is required to reach say , 30psi, and the pressure in the boiler is  that just by evaporation, without reaching boiling point.Can this steam be used?

Comment: Can the steam be used for what?

Comment: To do work. Is it possible to get the gaseous  form of water capable of doing work without boiling the water

Comment: Yes. But why? This has to be more inefficient then boiling the water to steam to do work. As most power plants do.

Comment: I’m just curious as to if its possible. It will help me with the understanding of the vapor pressure concept